# Can I create/use static libraries in C# for Silverlight windows phone project?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, static-libraries

Is there a possibility to use static (.lib) libraries with C# silverlight project? I have searched all over the internet and found no proper solution for using static libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static libraries are C++ libraries. You can't use them directly from C# but there are ways to do interop:

1. Wrap the C++ classes in a C++/CLI assembly
2. If you can modify the static library code, make the C++ classes COM classes (using ATL) and let the CLR do the wrapping

Comment: As i am new for the topic , will you please elaborate on this more and how i can refer the final assembly in my windows phone project?

Comment: You should provide more info so that I can tell you which of the two options is better. Like, did you create the static library or is it a third-party library? And what kind of library is it (what does it do)?